# Can I set a default display arrangement for when I connect to a new Screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I would like to set a default display arrangement for when I connect my laptop to an unknown screen.

My background here is that I mostly work at the university labs, which means I basically have a new display every time I start working.

When I plug the VGA into my laptop, it automatically switches into this mode:

[image: Default display arrangement]

Now, the VGA socket of my laptop happens to be on the left side, so I always place the laptop to the right of the bigger screen.
And since that is not going to change until I buy a new one, I would love to be able to make the default behaviour this:

[image: Desired display arrangement]

Is there any way to do this? Maybe in the xorg.conf or such?
I am running purely on Intel graphics at the moment since my hybrid Nvidia chip is not worth the trouble.